# POST variables not being passed by jQuery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying for hours to get call a php function when a button is clicked. The ajax.php file is being opened and it is returning fine, however the post variables are not being passed. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#button-id").click(function() {
        $.post('functions/ajax.php',
          { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" },
          function(data) {
              alert(data);
          }
        );
    });
});
```

And the following php code results in an empty array being displayed.

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why the data variables aren't being passed to the ajax.php file. What could be causing this?

Comment: You're not getting console errors correct? And I assume you are running this on an actual server?

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: @aug Yes, I am running this on a local server and no I am not getting any console errors.

Comment: Your code returns: `Array ( [param1] => value1 [param2] => value2 )`

Comment: have you add jquery.js ?

Comment: @MrUpsidown is there anything that could be causing the variables to not get passed for me?

Comment: @Khushboo Yes, the jQuery is executing fine, the only thing not working is the variables are not being posted.

Comment: I guess it's just a typo but you are missing `);` at the end of your `$(function() {`.

Comment: You're right it was a typo, my actual code has the missing ');'.

Comment: Could it be something to do with Bootstrap 3's jQuery handling?

Comment: No. It works with bootstrap included too.

Comment: I have stripped it down to just html tags, the button, the jquery source, and the ajax code and I get the same result. Could it be something to do with server settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was being caused by my .htaccess file. Because I was redirecting all .php file requests to their respective page without the .php extension, an extra get request was being executed each time the file was opened, resulting in all the previous post variables being lost.

Comment: How did you fix this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this:

```
$.post("functions/ajax.php", {
    param1: "value1",
    param2: "value2"
}).done(function (data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ (under examples)

Answer (score 0):

This will helpful for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url:"<?=Yii::app()->createUrl('site/Enquiryvalidation');?>",
    data:{"param1: "value1", param2: "value2"},
    success:function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue being caused by my .htaccess removing the php file extensions. To fix this, simply remove the php extension in the request:

```
$.post('functions/ajax',
    { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```